# Azure CLI list VMs with associated public IP

Tags: arrays, azure, format, command-line-interface

I need to list azure VMs with associated IP addresses.

When I run
`az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group RG --query "[[].virtualMachine.name, [].virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses[0].ipAddress]"` the output is

```
[
  [
    "Server1",
    "Server2"
  ],
  [
    "20.25.36.153",
    "20.84.93.126"
  ]
]
```

but I need it to be better formated, e.g.

```
Server1 20.25.36.153
Server2 20.84.93.126
```

Is there a better az cli way to achieve what I want?
Or do I need to somehow flatten this nested array? I tried to do that as well but need some assistance. I use bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command to get the Ip addresses in table format

```
az vm list-ip-addresses -o table
```

which  will give you the list of VM's in your subscription and you can use `-g` to get the list of the particular resource group

[image]